# How to read iPhone system logs?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod, logs

Does the iphone (and ipod/pad?) have an equivalent to the [Windows Event Log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer)? How can one read it?

I'd like to examine the event log for things like unlock events (successful and failed), charging times (connect/disconnect), network access (connect/disconnect) for both wifi and data, and power cycles (on/off). Bonus points for what apps run and when. All going back several weeks (if possible).

I want to check existing history, not install something on the device that will track this kind of information going forward. I would also prefer not to install something in order to get historical logs, but will do so if that's the only route forward. I don't have a Mac, but do have Windows 7 (and Linux if need be).

The devices are not jailbroken and running iOS 8.

Comment: You can't unless you have enrolled in the iOS developer program. Even enrolled, you only have access to certain kind of logs (energy, networking...).

Comment: Interesting. Never pondered that Console could read logs on a remote device. I sometimes peruse the logs that are downloaded during an iTunes sync process. And I wonder how well iOS does housekeeping, since even benign things are logged, and that can add up over time on a device with limited space.

Comment: Settings -> Privacity -> Analitycs -> Analysis Data

Comment: @LF This worked; iPadOS 16.7.2

Answer (score 18):

This can only be done on a mac:

- Connect your device to a Mac
- Open Xcode, go to Window->Devices in the title bar
- Click on your device from the sidebar
- Click 'View Device Logs'

You don't need to be enrolled in a developer program to be able to do this. To this on windows you'll probably need some sort of virtual machine/hackintosh

Answer (score 8):

As Samantha said, it can only be done on a mac.

[Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) is a free macOS app published by Apple.
Among other features, it allows access to the device logs.

1. Download and install 
   [Apple Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) on a Mac (~65 MB free disk space required)
2. Connect the iOS device to the Mac and trust the computer
3. Start the Apple Configurator 2
4. Within the "All Devices" view double-click on the device attached to the Mac. An overview of the device is shown
5. On the left hand menu bar click on "Console". The console of the device opens showing a live log

Comment: Using the XCode IDE for people who not developer is uncool. That's why this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can view the logs of an attached iDevice, without installing any extra software on a Mac, by just using the **Console** app (usually found in Applications/Utilities folder). When you run the Console app the attached device will show up under the Devices in the left panel of the app. If you click on the device you can see and search its log.