# Logs of installed applications

Tags: logs

Based on this question: [How to read iPhone system logs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/165100/how-to-read-iphone-system-logs)
Will I find in these logs when applications were installed?

Comment: a slightly less cumbersome way to see App Store purchases in App Store itself. It doesn't list subsequent removals and downloads though.

Comment: What would be the best is to show every time the application was installed. But thanks for the tips ;)