# Viewing login attempts on an iOS device

Tags: iphone, password, logs, unlock, face-id

Is there a way to access a log of login attempts on an iOS device? I'm specifically looking for the following:

- When was the function activated for the first time?
- Dates and time that the device has been unlocked
- When the function was deactivated and activated again?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a user accessible log that's maintained at all times on iOS devices. However, if you connect your iOS device to a Mac, you can view login attempts and information through the Console app. [After connecting your iOS device to your computer, open the Console app and click on your iOS device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/383449); you may be prompted to unlock and grant permissions on your iOS device. You can then start streaming messages. Search for AuthenticationServicesAgent. You'll see a variety of messages, including but not limited to the lock status of the device:

[image]